# Keeping track of added element in an array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm playing around with vue.js and the .vue components, and as newbie, I'm wondering how can I keep track of the element I add in the array.

The situation is the following :

1. The user add a new element from a form
2. When he submit, the data are automatically added to a ul>li element, and a POST request is made to the API
3. When the POST is done, I want to update the specific li with the new data from the server.

The thing is, I can not target the last li because the server can take time to process the request (he do a lot of work), so the user may have added 1, 5, 10 other entries in the meantime.

So how can I do ?

Here's my code so far :

```
<template>
    <form method="post" v-on:submit.prevent="search">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Person name" required v-model="name" v-el="nameInput" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Company" required v-model="company" v-el="domainInput" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn show-m" />
    </form>
    <ul>
        <li transition="expand" v-for="contact in contacts">
            <img v-bind:src="contact.avatar_url" width="40px" height="40px" class="cl-avatar" />
            <div class="cl-user">
                <strong class="cl-name">{{contact.name}} <span class="cl-company">{{contact.company}}</span></strong>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            contacts: [],
            name: null,
            company: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        search: function (event) {
            this.$http.post('/search', {
                name: this.name,
                company: this.company
            }).then(function (xhr) {
                // HERE ! How can I target the exact entry ?
                this.contacts.unshift(xhr.data)
            })

            this.name = ''
            this.company = ''

            this.contacts.unshift({'name': this.name, 'company': this.company})
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Thank you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a working solution : I use a component instead of `<li />` for each entries, and manage the state of these inside the component :

```
<ul>
    <contact-entry v-for="contact in contacts" v-bind:contact="contact"></contact-entry>
</ul>
```

That way, when I add a new entry in the array (described above), a new instance of the component `contact-entry` is made.

Inside that component, I did the following :

```
<script>
export default {
    props: ['contact'],
    created: function () {
        if (this.contact.id === undefined) { // If it's a new contact
            this.$http.post('search/name', { // I do the post here
                name: this.contact.name,
                domain: this.contact.company.name
            }).then(function (xhr) {
                this.contact = xhr.data // This will update the data once the server has replied, without hassle to find the correct line
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

That's it ! :) In the parent's component, I removed the xhr request and simplified the method to :

```
<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            contacts: [],
            name: null,
            company: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        search: function (event) {
            this.name = ''
            this.company = ''

            this.contacts.unshift({'name': this.name, 'company': this.company})
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the `name` and `company` fields are unique you could search through the array to find it... otherwise you can just wait to append it to the array until the return function:

```
    search: function (event) {
        this.$http.post('/search', {
            name: this.name,
            company: this.company
        }).then(function (xhr) {
            this.contacts.unshift(xhr.data)
        })

        this.name = ''
        this.company = ''
    },
```